# Launching thread from constructor a taboo?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here are two toy implementations of  launch of a thread from an object - one from constructor and another from a member function. I have searched SO without a concrete answer. I still don't get when SO guru says **Don't launch a thread from the constructor**, what are the possible issues if I launch from constructor. What advantages implement II over I than?

**Implementation 1: Launch from member function**

```
class foo {
    thread th;
public:

    foo() {     
    }

    void run() {
        th = thread([]() {
            cout << " New thread \n";
        });
    }

    ~foo() {
        cout << " Thread joining\n";
        th.join();
    }
};

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        foo f;
        f.run();
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Implementation 2: Launch In Constructor**

```
class foo {
    thread th;
public:
    foo() {
        th = thread([]() {
            cout << " New thread \n";
        });
    }
    ~foo() {
        cout << " Thread joining\n";
        th.join();
    }
};

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        foo();
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My 1st idea is : if your constructor fails after starting the thread, you won't be able to get and handle your thread has you wont have any reference to it anymore.

Comment: Constructors such as these are no throw and no except, what possibly can go wrong? Is it related to resource managed classes only?

Comment: I guess nothing in this one. But you asked for a general best practice explaination. Can you be sure that all the constructors you will implement will be simple ? Because if you are currently wondering whether you can start a thread from a constructor then you already don't match the "simple constructors" approach ;-)

Comment: One common issue is that developers assume that, when the thread code gets execution, the ctor that created it has already run to completion.  If that does not happen, and so the ctor has not yet created/initialized resources that the thread tries to use, then..... :)

Comment: With care, you can do it, and then you can, for instance, create subsystems with one ctor call, avoiding the nasties of multi-stage construction, (and worse -having to document it:)